# How do I move an Edge but keep it aligned?

Tags: modeling

I've deleted a face and want to move one of the edges further into the space I've created (Nearer to the circle in the first image).

Normally I would press G to move it and then x or y or z to constraint it, so that I don't lose my alignment. However this time I'm on a slope so it needs to be constrained to the X AND Z axis (See image 2). Any ideas how I achieve this?

What I've tried:
Vertex slide won't help and I've tried to use scale Z with 2 Edges selected which was close however the object isn't symmetrical. I just need to move the 1 Edge.

[image: FRONT]

[image: SIDE]

Comment: A custom orientation probably helps? Select the face and press + sign here: https://i.imgur.com/QtuYapB.png

Answer (score 0):

Welcome BSE.
You can create a new transform orientation by selecting the edge that you want and clicking here.
In your case here

> However this time I'm on a slope

Select the slope edge and click on plus button. Once you do that try to move some vertices.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new transformation wasn't getting the result I wanted. Another option to snap to edge was close but gave some odd results.

[image]

I went a different way around it and subdivided  the edges on the left and right hand sides, which I could slide using GG. Once the vertexes were in place I added a new face using F

[image]

[image]